# How / why do infrared thermometers work?

Tags: thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation

How can reading the intensity of infrared radiation coming from an object let you calculate its temperature?   Could any wavelength be used to measure temperature - why infrared, and not, for instance, green, or low frequency radio waves?  And would an infrared thermometer give an accurate temperature of, say, an infrared LED?

Comment: Some of your questions are answered in this auricle.  https://www.omega.co.uk/temperature/Z/pdf/z059-062.pdf

Comment: The radiation intensity at every
wavelength is a strict function of the temperature. By
measuring the intensity of the radiation one can therefore
determine the object’s temperature(see Planck's radiation graph);  for details see: https://www.tuhh.de/mt/ftir/lib/RemoteTemperature/pyrometry.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every object with nonzero temperature (so, every object) radiates EM radiation
2. The spectrum of a black body (that is, a body that absorbs all light at all wavelengths) is given by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law).
3. Generally, nothing is completely black (except for empty space, which is why cosmic microwave background has a very nice black body radiation spectrum). In general, emissivity varies with wavelength: everything that reflects some light (has color in any part of the spectrum) doesn't follow Planck's law anymore, it multiplies it by some factor for each wavelength.

Conclusion: you can measure the temperature using the Planck's law by measuring *emitted* light at some wavelength (or many wavelengths for an accurate reading), *only if* the object is black at that wavelength. It's handy to do this in that portion of the infrared spectrum, where most materials have no special behaviour. In green wavelengths, it would only work for black, red and blue objects (but not for green/yellow/cyan/anything that reflects green). In radio wavelengths, the signals would be way too weak to detect with such a small sensor, and also, due to large wavelength, there's no way to target the measurement to a small object (you'd basically get an average of half the sky due to diffraction), and if an object itself is smaller than the wavelength, it's emission footprint is small (it's basically transparent for that wavelength, so the assumptions required for the Planck's law to work don't hold.

Comment: That's very helpful - as a followup question, looking at the emission spectrum given by Planck's Law, why does it peak so significantly in the visible / infrared area of the spectrum?   Similarly, why would most common materials be black in the infrared wavelengths?

Comment: The peak wavelength depends on the temperature, according to Wien's law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law

For room temperature objects, it's in infrared... for glowing hot objects, it's in visible.

What wavelengths a material absorbs depends in resonances in their response to EM waves. Usually, rotational and vibrational molecular resonances are in microwaves and IR, and resonances of electrons in the molecule are usually in visual or/and UV spectrum. There are gaps between, for which the materials are relatively transparent.